# Apache HTTP Server has stopped working - curl

Tags: php, apache, curl

I use curl to get data from the page

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $page);     
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $raw= str_get_html($str);
```

where `$page` is url to a page

It works great but when i try to get to get data from page that is larger then normal my apache stops responding

This is apache log:

```
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3908
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Child 3908: Child process is running
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Child 3908: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Child 3908: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Child 3908: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:53 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
```

I think that size of page is a problem ( am not sure ) , can someone confirm that? And is there any way to fix this ? I tried to increase memory_alocation in php.ini but it didn't help

Comment: and "larger than normal" means what size in more measurable units?

Comment: Do you know the size of the content you're loading?

Comment: also, there is no `memory_alocation` configuration item. Do you mean `memory_limit`?

Comment: when i say larger then normal i mean larger pages with witch it works fine. when i saved page it was 231 KB htm file.
y i was refering to memory_limit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your php page gets timeout because getting page lasts so long, you can disable timeout with [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Place that line at start of your script.

Comment: i did set time limit in curl
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
but i dont get time out i get apache crash

Comment: That timeout option is for cURL, I'm talking about the PHP timeout, the page where you're running those cURL calls could timeout independly of your CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT option. Default php timeout is 30 seconds.